Deque vs list for LRU Cache Implementation
I was trying to implement LRU Cache for a Leetcode question. My final code is below and it works fine. However, my first choice was deque instead of list with exactly same procedure and I was getting wrong results while using deque. I saw the posts about "deque vs list" but I couldn't figure out the reason. Why my code is working good for list and giving inconsistent results for deque?
class LRUCache 
{
public:
    list<int> dq;
    unordered_map <int, pair<int, list<int>::iterator>> mp;

    int size{};

    LRUCache(int capacity) 
    {
      size = capacity;  
    }
    

    int get(int key) 
    {
       int returnvalue{-1};
       
       if(mp.find(key) != mp.end())
       {
         returnvalue = mp[key].first;
         dq.erase(mp[key].second);
         dq.push_front(key);
         mp[key].second = dq.begin();
       }

      return returnvalue; 
    }
    
    void put(int key, int value) 
    {
       if(mp.find(key) != mp.end())
       { 
         dq.erase(mp[key].second);
         dq.push_front(key);
         mp[key] = {value,dq.begin()};
       }

       else
       {
         if(dq.size() < size)
         {
            dq.push_front(key);
            mp[key] = {value,dq.begin()};
         }
         else
         {
            mp.erase(dq.back());
            dq.pop_back();
            dq.push_front(key);
            mp[key] = {value,dq.begin()};         
         } 
       } 

    }
};


To get a good answer you probably need to post the code that didn't work.

A list is special in that each element is allocated separately. That keeps iterators stable while deleting other members of the list. For a deque, not so - deleting an element can invalidate iterators to other elements.

@ 500 - Internal Server Error Only changes are in line 4 and 5 as : deque dq;
unordered_map <int, pair<int, deque::iterator>> mp;

Handy reading: Iterator Invalidation Rules

From the problem description, "get" is only an accessor and does not cause mutation, only "put" does. The cache is meant to operate using the FIFO behaviour where "put" on a full instance of the data structure causes an eviction. You don’t need a double ended queue because you will only be adding to one end.

deque iterators are invalidated on every size changing operation on the deque. Beyond that, erasing an iterator in the middle takes linear time for a deque, constant time for a list. Plus, for a list you can combine the erase + push_front into one dq.splice(dq.begin(), dq, mp[key].second) which doesn't need to deallocate and reallocate. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice
